# Perl-Starman (PSGI) + PHP = Apache2 proxy setup? - How to do?

Tags: php, perl, apache2, plack

How to run together: PSGI and PHP?

I have Perl/PSGI application (running under pure perl Starman server). Now, for some reason need run one PHP application too ;(, so (probably) need Apache2. Questions:

- really need Apache for PHP? or exists some other solution?
- How to setup reverse proxy, so when someone will go to http: //mysite/myapp/something, will be proxied to Starman where my PSGI "myapp" living? and
- http: //mysite/phpapp/anything - will go to php app...
- I can setup the Starman server for listening on another port, e.g. 8080, but want access both applications at port:80 - so need reverse proxy.

Plus:

the server is behind my home NAT router. Internal server has address: 192.168.1.10, from the outside, ofc, the router have correct internet address. I have redirected all traffic

```
routerIP:80 -> 192.168.1.10:80
```

- What is best way achieve access to both applications: PSGI + PHP from the both side (internet + "intranet") at the port:80?
- Need setup some virtual hosts? Or exists some really simple solution?
- some links to helpful guidelines shoudl help a lot too..

Ps: I don't need optimize performance, the server is only for home/demo/testing purpose.

*EDIT:
Now, in another similar situation I checked CPAN again and based on @rawhide's answer I found the [Plack::App::PHPCGI](http://search.cpan.org/~kazeburo/Plack-App-PHPCGI-0.03/lib/Plack/App/PHPCGI.pm) module. Works great - it is **really cool** testing php apps under plackup... ;)*

Comment: Voting to move this question to Serverfault.

Comment: I decided here instead serverfault because the ServerFault FAQ: and it is not about …
 * Networking outside the professional workplace
 * Running servers at home for personal use - and this IS for personal use... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can execute it as CGI (fork+exec) either using `Plack::App::CGIBin` or using WrapCGI directly

```
my $rawapp = Plack::App::WrapCGI->new(script => "rawhide.php" , execute => 1 )->to_app;
builder {
    mount "/rawhide" => $rawapp ;
};
```

If rawhide.php has no shebang, you'd use `/usr/bin/php /path/to/rawhide.php`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to run Apache2 and PHP on port 80, and install mod_proxy to the Apache process and reverse proxy some of the path to the backend Starman. You can also run php using php-fpm as a FastCGI, and do the same thing.

Since it is a demo purpose, you can go crazy and run Starman on port 80 instead, and then use Plack::App::FCGIDispatcher to "mount" the FastCGI PHP process. I tried that once - it worked well, but probably only for the demo purpose, not for the production use.

Comment: Why not simply use starman instead? See: http://search.cpan.org/~miyagawa/Starman/bin/starman